# Does linking a static library twice result in duplication?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a project that links to both OpenCV and cvBlob, but cvBlob also links to OpenCV. Both OpenCV and cvBlob are built as static libraries.

Does my executable have 2 copies of all OpenCV functions that are used by both my code and by cvBlob, or does the linker detect this and remove the redundancy?

cvBlob and my code link to the same OpenCV lib files.

Comment: This is actually a very common situation - *everybody* links to the CRT for example. The linker handles it without a sweat.

Comment: What happens though in the case that there are two different versions of the same library? Is it non-deterministic which will actually get used?

Comment: If you have *different* .lib files that implement the same functions, you'll get "duplicate symbol" errors/warnings at link time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they both link to the same .lib files, then there is only one copy in the final executable.

Comment: How is it determined that it is the same .lib file? By path?   What about linking two different dynamicly loaded libraries that include the same lib?   Do you by chance have some link to documentation / other material for digging into this?